# Spark streaming from local file to hdfs. textFileStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to stream local directory content to HDFS. This local directory will be modified by a script and contents will be added for every 5 seconds. My spark program will stream this local directory contents and save them to HDFS. However, when I start streaming nothing is happening. 
I checked the logs but I didn't get a hint.

Let me explain the scenario. A shell script will moves a file with some data for every 5 seconds in the local directory. The duration object of streaming context is also 5 seconds. As the script moves a new file, atomicity is maintained here if I am not wrong. For every five seconds receivers will process the data and create Dstream object. I just searched about streaming local directories and found that the path should be provided as ”file:///my/path”. I didn't tried with this format. But if this is the case then how the spark executors of the nodes will maintain the common state of the local path provided?

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
val filestream = ssc.textFileStream("/home/karteekkhadoop/ch06input")
import java.sql.Timestamp
case class Order(time: java.sql.Timestamp, orderId:Long, clientId:Long, symbol:String, amount:Int, price:Double, buy:Boolean)
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
val orders = filestream.flatMap(line => {
    val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    var s = line.split(",")
    try {
        assert(s(6) == "B" || s(6) == "S")
        List(Order(new Timestamp(dateFormat.parse(s(0)).getTime()), s(1).toLong, s(2).toLong, s(3), s(4).toInt, s(5).toDouble, s(6)=="B"))
    }catch{
        case e: Throwable => println("Wrong line format("+e+") : " + line)
        List()
    }
})

val numPerType = orders.map(o => (o.buy, 1L)).reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)
numPerType.repartition(1).saveAsTextFiles("/user/karteekkhadoop/ch06output/output", "txt")
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Paths given are absolute and exists. I am also including the following logs.

```
[karteekkhadoop@gw03 stream]$ yarn logs -applicationId application_1540458187951_12531
18/11/21 11:12:35 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at rm01.itversity.com/172.16.1.106:8050
18/11/21 11:12:35 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at rm01.itversity.com/172.16.1.106:10200
Container: container_e42_1540458187951_12531_01_000001 on wn02.itversity.com:45454
LogAggregationType: LOCAL
==================================================================================
LogType:stderr
LogLastModifiedTime:Wed Nov 21 10:52:00 -0500 2018
LogLength:5320
LogContents:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hdp01/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/2693/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
18/11/21 10:51:57 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
18/11/21 10:51:57 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
18/11/21 10:51:57 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
18/11/21 10:51:57 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: yarn,karteekkhadoop
18/11/21 10:51:57 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: yarn,karteekkhadoop
18/11/21 10:51:57 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
18/11/21 10:51:57 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
18/11/21 10:51:57 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(yarn, karteekkhadoop); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(yarn, karteekkhadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set()
18/11/21 10:51:58 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/11/21 10:51:58 INFO ApplicationMaster: Preparing Local resources
18/11/21 10:51:59 WARN DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
18/11/21 10:51:59 INFO ApplicationMaster: ApplicationAttemptId: appattempt_1540458187951_12531_000001
18/11/21 10:51:59 INFO ApplicationMaster: Waiting for Spark driver to be reachable.
18/11/21 10:51:59 INFO ApplicationMaster: Driver now available: gw03.itversity.com:38932
18/11/21 10:51:59 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to gw03.itversity.com/172.16.1.113:38932 after 90 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
18/11/21 10:51:59 INFO ApplicationMaster: 
===============================================================================
YARN executor launch context:
  env:
    CLASSPATH -> {{PWD}}<CPS>{{PWD}}/__spark_conf__<CPS>{{PWD}}/__spark_libs__/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop/conf<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/ext/hadoop/*<CPS>$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.2.6.5.0-292.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf/secure:/usr/hdp/current/ext/hadoop/*<CPS>{{PWD}}/__spark_conf__/__hadoop_conf__
    SPARK_YARN_STAGING_DIR -> *********(redacted)
    SPARK_USER -> *********(redacted)

  command:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" \ 
      {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java \ 
      -server \ 
      -Xmx1024m \ 
      -Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp \ 
      '-Dspark.history.ui.port=18081' \ 
      '-Dspark.driver.port=38932' \ 
      '-Dspark.port.maxRetries=100' \ 
      -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR> \ 
      -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' \ 
      org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend \ 
      --driver-url \ 
      spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@gw03.itversity.com:38932 \ 
      --executor-id \ 
      <executorId> \ 
      --hostname \ 
      <hostname> \ 
      --cores \ 
      1 \ 
      --app-id \ 
      application_1540458187951_12531 \ 
      --user-class-path \ 
      file:$PWD/__app__.jar \ 
      1><LOG_DIR>/stdout \ 
      2><LOG_DIR>/stderr

  resources:
    __spark_libs__ -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "nn01.itversity.com" port: 8020 file: "/hdp/apps/2.6.5.0-292/spark2/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz" } size: 202745446 timestamp: 1533325894570 type: ARCHIVE visibility: PUBLIC
    __spark_conf__ -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "nn01.itversity.com" port: 8020 file: "/user/karteekkhadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1540458187951_12531/__spark_conf__.zip" } size: 248901 timestamp: 1542815515889 type: ARCHIVE visibility: PRIVATE

===============================================================================
18/11/21 10:51:59 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at rm01.itversity.com/172.16.1.106:8030
18/11/21 10:51:59 INFO YarnRMClient: Registering the ApplicationMaster
18/11/21 10:51:59 INFO Utils: Using initial executors = 0, max of spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors, spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and spark.executor.instances
18/11/21 10:52:00 INFO ApplicationMaster: Started progress reporter thread with (heartbeat : 3000, initial allocation : 200) intervals
End of LogType:stderr.This log file belongs to a running container (container_e42_1540458187951_12531_01_000001) and so may not be complete.
```

What is wrong with the code. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use local directory like that. As with any Spark readers, input (and output) storage has to be accessible from each node (driver and executors) and all nodes have to see exactly the same state.

Additionally please remember that for file system sources, changes to files have to be atomic (like file system move), and non-atomic operations (like appending to file) won't work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me explain the scenario. A shell script will move a file with some data for every 5 seconds into the local directory. The duration object of streaming context is also 5 seconds. As the script moves the entire file, atomicity is maintained here if I am not wrong. For every five seconds receivers will process the data and create Dstream object with mini batch RDD’s. I just searched about streaming local directories and found that the path should be provided as ”file:///my/path”. I didn't tried with this format. But if this is the case then how the spa

Comment: @karteek You just can't use a local file system for Spark... The code runs in YARN, in the entire cluster, on any machine, not just that's one machine where you run it

Comment: I am following Spark in Action book 2017 version. In that book, in chapter 06 author clearly mentioned about using local directory. Please refer to this link https://github.com/spark-in-action/first-edition/blob/master/ch06/splitAndSend.sh In this script author gave two options for the streaming directory. I can use s3 instead of a local directory. But I just don't understand why the author mentioned about local directory if we can't stream through the local directory in spark.

Comment: Please refer to this link as well. https://github.com/spark-in-action/first-edition/blob/master/ch06/scala/ch06-listings.scala Please reply with your comment on this. I am really confused.